# Why do inflight wifi networks display a captcha?

Tags: wifi

When you log on to Gogo Inflight Wifi or similar, Gogo displays a captcha:

[image]

A CAPTCHA is usually associated with preventing automated traffic from accessing your network; however, to connect to Gogo you need to be *on the plane*, thirty thousand feet in the air. It doesn't seem like this is exploitable by bots (or what the advantage would be from doing so).

What am I missing?

Comment: It's most likely used to thwart bruteforce, as on a local network (Wi-Fi) with good reception you can have nearly zero latency and good bandwidth which would allow you to simultaneously try hundreds of combinations per second, and the fact that it's a local network and there's no way to identify someone (other than via a spoofable MAC address) means they have no way to hold someone liable for the eventual damage/fraud/financial losses. This captcha however is a pure joke though.

Comment: @André The MAC may be technically spoofable, but since you're in a confined area and operating wirelessly it's still easy to track down which device is using it during an active attack if you have the right equipment and expertise. That said, the risk generally is low enough that most airlines won't care about equipping their staff with the necessary tools or skills.

Comment: @Iszi true, except in most cases you don't even need bruteforce - all you have to do is spoof the MAC of a customer, as the manufacturers of these systems still use an unencrypted network for all clients.

Comment: I also love how they *attempt to* verify you're human **after** they have taken your money.

Comment: Since the header says "activation of service", I guess that if the captcha was closed down without entering it, the pass would stay in account and can be used later. And that this captcha is used to allow the user to save pre-purchased passes in the account to be used later.

Comment: @André No it wouldnt prevent brute force, since the sign in is at step 2. At the time the attacker arrives at captcha, he would know the correct password. So this is more a safety against inadvertient activation of service.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect this is to prevent inadvertient activation of service.

Imagine you have bougt a one-hour pass to use at a later time. When you start up your computer, your computer might try to update its antivirus, or may try to download some windows updates, thus prematurely starting your one-hour pass when you dont want.

Thus, they have a captcha to activate a pass (regardless of its a pre-purchased pass in your account or a pass that you purchase on the spot) just so you don't inadvertly activate the pass without your consent.

For example, look at these roaming "accidents", where a phone in the background, decides to download a software update or whatever, causing bills long above € 10 000, without the consent of the end user.
Thats why EU have done legalisation in the whole EU requiring all operators to require confirm each € 500, eg for each € 500 spent, the account must be blocked and require re-confirm to start billing again.

A captcha is not only to prevent "bots", its also used to make it clear you are doing a sensitive action, for example lets say deleting some important files, some software might ask you to type "Yes, I really want to delete this file!" in a text box or just ask to "enter 4252562 to delete the file".
To prevent auto-complete from kicking in, it can be good idea to use captcha or whatever.

So this captcha is more as a "confirm activation of pass" so you can't come and complain after this like "wtf? My pass is gone and I haven't activated it" (but in the background some software on your computer activated it). Its a service from the Company to you as a customer.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  The captcha comes after you log in with username and password, or buy the access with a payment method.  The captcha doesn't add anything on top of that in terms of a 'consenting to the service'.

Comment: @ThomasVanderStichele Yes it do. Imagine you don't want to surf right now. But you have a antivirus or updates in the OS. If the pass activated automatically, it would spend those hours without consent from you when antivirus/OS updated. The captcha then prevents activation of the pass unless there is a human present. Also be aware that apparently you can buy multiple passes and store them, and not use them until for later. Yes a button would be sufficent, but they would want to be extremely sure that you really want to "start" your pass.

Answer (score -5):

It's also so nobody can commit a violent act against a plane mid-flight.  If you can program a device to wake up at a specific time and automatically connect itself to the Internet by scripting the in-flight wifi purchase, you have just built yourself a remote detonator.  We live in scary, scary times.